# "Float"Object Isn't Callable Error in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop

i can't under stand why this error out

```
class Game:
  # Write Class Content
  def __init__(self,game_name,dev_name,year,game_prices):
      self.name=game_name
      self.developer=dev_name
      self.yer=year
      self.prices=game_prices

game_one = Game("FIFA", "EA Sports", 1994,780.0)

print(f"Game Name Is \"{game_one.name}\", ", end="".capitalize())
print(f"Developer Is \"{game_one.developer}\", ", end="".capitalize())
print(f"Release Date Is \"{game_one.yer}\", ", end="")
print(f"Price In Egypt Is {game_one.prices()}egyptian pounds".title())

# # Needed Output
# # "Game Name Is "fifa", Developer Is "ea sports", Release Date Is "1994", Price In Egypt Is 780.0 Egyptian Pounds"
```

The Output:

```
Game Name Is "FIFA", Developer Is "EA Sports", Release Date Is "1994", Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\OMAR\projects\st py proj\mymain.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(f"Price In Egypt Is {game_one.prices()}egyptian pounds".title())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Change `game_one.prices()` to `game_one.prices`

Comment: Part of learning to program is understanding error messages. The error is "'float' object is not callable" and the message shows you `game_one.prices()` as the culprit.  Now you can easily see that there is the object `game_one.prices` and you try to call it with `()`. What you do with this knowledge depends on the context. Here it is the removal of `()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you are trying to call a float object(which is game_one.prices). Now, python thinks that you are trying to call game_one.prices because you have added the parentheses. You need to change game_one.prices() to game_one.prices. Modified code:

```
print(f"Game Name Is \"{game_one.name}\", ", end="".capitalize())
print(f"Developer Is \"{game_one.developer}\", ", end="".capitalize())
print(f"Release Date Is \"{game_one.yer}\", ", end="")
print(f"Price In Egypt Is {game_one.prices}egyptian pounds".title())
```